# Многоуровневое меню на Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Создал главное меню сайта (по горизонтали), вставил в него подменюшку... А вот как дальше делать уровни?

Вот пример: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar Как дальше уровни в Dropdown продолжить?

Comment: Добавте в вопрос примеры кода с указанием куда и что вы хотите добавить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы имеете ввиду дочерные меню такого типа?

```
<ul>
  <li>1st lvl</li>
  <li>1st lvl</li>
    <li>
       <ul>
           <li>2nd level</li>
           <li>2nd level</li>
           <li>
                      <ul>
           <li>3rd level</li>
           <li>3rd level</li>
           <li>3rd level</li>
                      </ul>
           </li>
       </ul>
           </li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Да, это самое! Как сделать на Bootstrap? Я смог сделать только одну вложенность....

Comment: @sitev_ru, минутку. У меня как раз есть проект на Bootstrap'е. Сейчас напишу

Comment: @sitev_ru, http://cssdeck.com/labs/twitter-bootstrap-plain-collapsible-tree-menu Вот готовое примерное решение для меню

Comment: Немного не то... Вот пример: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/ Как дальше уровни в Dropdown продолжить?

Comment: Ага. Вот именно так Вы хотите. Сейчас подскажу. Пару минут обождите пожалуйста

Comment: @sitev_ru, Думаю такой вариант Вам должен подойти - http://jsfiddle.net/2Smgv/2858/

Comment: В вашем примере меню упало вниз... немного не то

Comment: Вам надо уровни в самом Dropdown?

Comment: да... в самом...

Comment: Сейчас сконструируем)

Comment: @sitev_ru, а что на счет http://cssdeck.com/labs/vmpxaege ?

Comment: Вот оно решение: http://www.bootply.com/0gMDXQS8uk

Comment: http://cssdeck.com/labs/vmpxaege мой вариант был примерно же такой, какой Вам надо было. Там просто есть submenu в ul li

Comment: Ну да почти, у вас подменю с галочкой какой-то... Её не нужно... Всё равно спасибо большое!